# Rewriting query string does not query anymore

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I made this one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    "find-new/posts&recent=1" [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /websitename/$1? [R=301,L]
```

Which does not work for me like I want it to be. I want to rewrite the `query url` of my site in to a `SEO friendly URL`, without losing it's working. **So it still has to query on the page to the most recent posts, but without showing the URL like the one I stated above. I want to change it to websitename only**. So http://websitename.com... there it has to query it. But now, it shows me a different page (the forum).

How can I do that? Is this possible? Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /sub-name/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /\?find-new/posts&recent=1\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /sub-name/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ ?$1?find-new/posts&recent=1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Nothing happens at all.

Comment: What was the URL that you used for testing this?

Comment: What do you mean? Can't give you a URL of the site cause of security reasons, but I can assure you that this snippet does not work. It does nothing for me.

Comment: Not asking for your real domain just interested in URI part. Just replace your domain name with `example.com`

Comment: So like this? `RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+\?(find-new/posts&recent=1)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /example.com/%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^example.com/(.+)$ /?$1 [L,NC,QSA]`

Comment: That is the code I gave you. The URL can be `http://example.com?find-new/posts&recent=1`

Comment: The URL is like this: `http://websitename.com/sub-name/find-new/posts&recent=1` if that is what you mean.

Comment: As I mentioned, this was `http://websitename.com/sub-name/find-new/posts&recent=1` working for me, but I don't want it to show the query, I just want to show the websitename only.

Comment: Where is query string in your URL? It has to start with with a question mark `?`

Comment: Ok so now your URL has changed. Q1. Is your .htaccess in `/sub-name/` folder? Q2: Do you want to keep SEO URL as `http://websitename.com/sub-name/find-new/posts&recent=1`?

Comment: Yes, pardon me, I forgot that. Yes, the htaccess is in that sub-name folder. I want to have an SEO URL and in this particular case, I want it to show: `http://websitename.com`, BUT, with the query being worked out. Because with my own snippet, it just redirects me to the page, without querying on the page. So I want the same functionality, but a different URL.

Comment: But try to understand this. if your SEO URL is `http://websitename.com` then query string gets discarded and internal URI `http://websitename.com/sub-name/find-new/posts&recent=1` won't work.

Comment: Hmm... what if we make it something like http://websitename.com/something.php? I mean, is it possible to now show the find-new.... area? So what you saying is that I can't rewrite the URL if I want the query?

Comment: ok see update, this is the only possible way. `http://websitename.com/sub-name/?find-new/posts&recent=1` will be redirected to `http://websitename.com/sub-name/`

Comment: But that's exactly the same as my snippet? It just redirects me to a different page, without doing the query?

Comment: No my rules are very different. There is no rule in your code that rewrites internally to `/sub-name/?find-new/posts&recent=1` Time for me to sign-off as it is very late.